# Plesk CLI database --create: This object can be created only in a subscription

Tags: mysql, database, shell, web-deployment, plesk

I'm using Plesk on a Linux root-server and want to write a simple deployment shell script.

To do that, I want to drop the database, create it again, and import a sql dump file.

I'm trying to create a database using:

```
plesk bin database --create myDbName -domain myDomain -type mysql -server localhost
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
This object can be created only in a subscription.
```

I was unable to find anything about this issue in the [Plesk docs](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/cli-linux/using-command-line-utilities/database-databases.40244/). How can I select the description that shall be used?

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you specified addition domain on the subscription as `myDomain`.

According to Plesk business logic, databases are associated with the webspace (or the subscription), not with the separate domains on the same subscription.
Basically, you should specify the name of the default domain for the subscription, which is the same as subscription name itself.

You can get the list of subscription names using `plesk bin subscription -l`. Then use the required name to create a database. For example:

```
# plesk bin subscription -l
domain.ltd
...
# plesk bin database --create myDbName -domain domain.ltd -type mysql -server localhost
```